# bcp sql command connection error

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello there please excuse my bad English also its the first time to ask about something over here .
i use this query to get specific table values and record them into text file

```
use SRO_VT_SHARD_Tito
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT * FROM SRO_VT_SHARD_Tito.._RefShopGoods " queryout "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Server Files\SMC\Patch_Internal\media\server_dep\silkroad\textdata\refshopgoods.txt" -T -c -w'
```

but i get an error and i dont know whats wrong or i dont know how to solve it

> Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0] A network-related
>   or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a
>   connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check
>   if instance name is correct and  if SQL Server is configured to allow
>   remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.

i already allowed the tcp/ip connection for sql server .

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have not specified the server instance name in the bcp command.

Should be:

```
bcp "SELECT * FROM SRO_VT_SHARD_Tito.._RefShopGoods " 
queryout "C:\...\refshopgoods.txt" -S [SERVERNAME] -T -c -w'
```

Check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) for more details on bcp utility.